# Matplotlib figure hangs in threading.Thread.join() is used

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib

Consider the following example

```
from time import sleep
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from threading import Thread
import numpy as np

class Monitor(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

        _, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.data = []

    def add_point(self, pt):
        self.data.append(pt)

        self.ax.cla()
        self.ax.plot(self.data)
        plt.draw()


class Main_job(Thread):

    def __init__(self, monitor):
        Thread.__init__(self)

        self.monitor = monitor

        self.output = []

    def run(self):
        for i in range(20):
            print(i)
            pt = np.random.rand()
            self.output.append(pt)
            self.monitor.add_point(pt)
            sleep(1)


monitor = Monitor()
monitor.start()

main = Main_job(monitor)
main.start()
```

I have a `Main_job` thread that perform a lengthy operation and I want to monitor it runtime.

I, therefore, defined a `Thread` for a `matplotlib` figure and another one for my process.

**The code runs fine**

Let's say now that I want to do something with the output of the `Main_job` thread before closing the program (e.g. printing it or saving it to a file).

I add the following lines at the end of my code

```
main.join()
print(main.output)
```

However, this interferes somehow with `matplotlib` that, despite not modifying at all the `monitor` thread, now hangs until `main` has finished.

How can I wait for `main` to finish, but at the same time avoid `monitor` to hang?

### EDIT 1 - Single threaded (non-working) version

Following FiddleStix request, here is a single-threaded version of the code. Despite being much simpler, in this version the figure hangs and is only displayed at the end of the process

```
from time import sleep
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

_, ax = plt.subplots()

output = []

for i in range(20):
    print(i)
    pt = np.random.rand()
    output.append(pt)

    ax.cla()
    ax.plot(output)

    sleep(1)
```

The situation can be slightly improved adding `plt.pause(0.01)` after plotting. This way, however, the figure is displayed, but the user can only interact during those 0.01s.

NOTE: I know the issue could be solved replacing `sleep(1)` with `plt.pause(1)`, but here `sleep` is only a proxy for a long a time-consuming operation in the real code, not just a pause.

Comment: Unless there's a lot more code not shown, I can't see any point at all to calling add_point from the Main_job thread.  Main_job.run() will wait for add_point to return in a synchronous way so it doesn't gain you anything.  Also, I'm not sure that Matplotlib is thread safe.  Also, your Monitor class doesn't have a run method so I don't think it does anything other than wait for add_point to be called.  The whole thing would be much simpler and less buggy if it was single threaded.

Comment: The code was originally single-threaded, but `matplotlib` was hanging during execution. The only way I found to avoid this is to put `matplotlib` in a separate thread.

If you can think of a simpler version where `matplotlib` is not hanging and that does not require `threading`, I'll be happy to accept the answer

Comment: If you post the single threaded code that was hanging (either here or in a new question) then one of us will be able to work out what the underlying issue is, I'm sure.  If there's enough code to actually run it (even if it's simplified) then so much the better.  EDIT: Oh and please let us know whether this is in a notebook or a normal python script.

Comment: Normal python script

Comment: I added a single threaded version of the code

Comment: Matplotlib is not thread-safe and GUIs must run in the main thread. Consider using any of the reportedly working solutions for animations in matplotlib instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make the Monitor thread a `daemon` thread ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon)). A daemon thread will automatically exit if the main thread stops. This way you can have something running in the background without explicitly stopping the second thread.

You can declare the thread as daemon simply by adding a class argument:

```
class Monitor(Thread):
    daemon = True
```

Comment: Do I need to keep the Main_job in a Thread class or can/should I move it to the main thread?

Comment: You can move it to the main thread. Keeping it seperate would only be useful if you require additional user/programmatic interaction during the calculations

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. However, this simply doesn't work. Just adding `daemon=True` to the code above (including `main.join()`) matplotlib keeps hanging and the figure is displayed only at the end

Answer (score 0):

The [GUI mainloop](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/faq/howto_faq.html?highlight=main%20thread#use-show) should run in the mainthread. Run your job in a separate thread so that it doesn't block the GUI.

A simple animation of the plot as `output` changes is achieved by performing a redraw using [matplotlib.pyplot.draw](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.draw.html#matplotlib-pyplot-draw) in the thread.

Consider using the [Animation API](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/animation_api.html?highlight=animation#module-matplotlib.animation) for a smooth animation of the live plot.

```
from time import sleep
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from threading import Thread
import numpy as np


_, ax = plt.subplots()

output = []

class Job(Thread):
    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            print(i)
            pt = np.random.rand()
            output.append(pt)
            sleep(1)
            ax.cla()
            ax.plot(output)
            plt.draw()

job = Job()
job.start()

plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but the code posted doesn't work. If you put `print(output)` at the end of the code, this is executed immediately (since we don't have `job.join()` this is expected) and just `[]` is printed. If, instead, we add `job.join(); print(output)` the output is correctly shown at the end, but the figure hangs exactly as it does now

Comment: I will try with the Animation API to see if it works.
PS: Sorry for the late reply

Comment: My answer addresses blocking of the main thread from rendering the chart due to a running background job. You can declare the operation on `output` in the end of the background job run function